# create a map of string from a JSON with unknow key-values in Go

Tags: json, string, dictionary, go, unmarshalling

I try to create a map of strings from a JSON with an undefined number of unknow key-values.

Here is my example JSON file:

```
{
         "localhost":
        {
                "tag": "dev_latest",
                "vhost": "localhost.com"
        },
        "development":
        {
                "tag": "dev_latest",
                "vhost": "dev.com"
        }
}
```

I want to create a `map[string]string` with value like this:

```
config := map[string]string{
    "localhost-tag":      "dev_latest",
    "localhost-vhost": "localhost.com,
    "development-tag":   "dev_latest,
    ...
}
```

To parse a JSON with `"github.com/jmoiron/jsonq"` with known values, is quite easy, but in this case, `localhost` can be anything and `tag` can be any other thing.

My entry point in my Go code is like this:

```
func ParseJson(){
    configPath := GetConfigPath()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(configPath) 

     //  Here, I need to create my map of strings..

    return configKeyStr

}
```

Any help will be really appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to do. Simply convert.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

const s = `
{
         "localhost":
        {
                "tag": "dev_latest",
                "vhost": "localhost.com"
        },
        "development":
        {
                "tag": "dev_latest",
                "vhost": "dev.com"
        }
}
`

func main() {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    mm := make(map[string]string)
    for k, v := range m {
        mm[k] = fmt.Sprint(v)
    }
    fmt.Println(mm)
}
```

## UPDATE

Wrote flatten (maybe works as charm)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

const s = `
{
         "localhost":
        {
                "tag": "dev_latest",
                "vhost": "localhost.com"
        },
        "development":
        {
                "tag": "dev_latest",
                "vhost": "dev.com"
        }
}
`

func flatten(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]string {
    mm := make(map[string]string)
    for k, v := range m {
        switch reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() {
        case reflect.Map:
            mv := flatten(v.(map[string]interface{}))
            for kk, vv := range mv {
                mm[k+"-"+kk] = vv
            }
        case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
            for kk, vv := range m {
                if reflect.TypeOf(vv).Kind() == reflect.Map {
                    mv := flatten(vv.(map[string]interface{}))
                    for kkk, vvv := range mv {
                        mm[k+"-"+kkk] = vvv
                    }
                } else {
                    mm[k+"-"+kk] = fmt.Sprint(vv)
                }
            }
        default:
            mm[k] = fmt.Sprint(v)
        }
    }
    return mm
}

func main() {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(flatten(m), "", "  ")
    println(string(b))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it work but It's not exactly what I want,

How Can I have a map like this : 

https://pastebin.com/6EJX01D6

Comment: `mm` is your expected?

Comment: I think he want *flatten map*, i.e. the JSON key is combined *recursively* with "-" as the separator.

Comment: Yes , It's exactly what I need, but I can't make it work :p

Comment: Ah, I understand you want just now.

Comment: But you will have problem when writing config file, I guess. Most of case, you can solve the xpath like solution. For example, json-pointer (https://github.com/mattn/go-jsonpointer) or something similar (https://github.com/mattn/go-scan)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this automatically, but you can range over the "internal" maps, and combine the outer keys with the inner keys using simple string concatenation (`+` operator). Also it's recommended to unmarshal directly into a value of `map[string]map[string]string` so you don't need to use type assertions. Also no need to use any external libraries for this, the standard [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package is perfectly enough for this.

Example:

```
var mm map[string]map[string]string
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &mm); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
config := map[string]string{}
for mk, m := range mm {
    for k, v := range m {
        config[mk+"-"+k] = v
    }
}
fmt.Println(config)
```

Output is as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ECMg7lgaKx)):

```
map[localhost-tag:dev_latest localhost-vhost:localhost.com
    development-tag:dev_latest development-vhost:dev.com]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Since in the question you mentioned *undefined number of unknown key-values*, you may need to deal with JSON document with unknown number of nesting level and having a value other than `string`. In this case, you need to `Unmarshal` json to `map[string]interface{}`, then use recursion to make *flat* map. Once the json document unmrashaled to `map[string]interface{}`, use the following function:

```
func flatMap(src map[string]interface{}, baseKey, sep string, dest map[string]string) {
    for key, val := range src {
        if len(baseKey) != 0 {
            key = baseKey + sep + key
        }
        switch val := val.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            flatMap(val, key, sep, dest)
        case string:
            dest[key] = val
        case fmt.Stringer:
            dest[key] = val.String()
        default:
            //TODO: You may need to handle ARRAY/SLICE

            //simply convert to string using `Sprintf`
            //NOTE: modify as needed.
            dest[key] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", val)
        }
    }
}
```

The working solution adapted from mattn answer at https://play.golang.org/p/9SQsbAUFdY

As pointed by mattn, you may have problem when you want to writeback the configuration value. In that case, use the existing library/framework.